# How to detect last character in a C string when within a getchar() loop

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following which allows the entering in of text:

```
printf("Enter in your text\n");
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    if (last_char) // the last character before the user presses enter.
        do_something();
}
```

Is there a way for me to detect if the character is the last one in the text input (without getting out of the loop)? Or is that not possible the current organization of things above?

Comment: `getch()` read input from the console, how do you gonna know its last character? you have to specify some character treated as the last character. for example -1 or 0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to detect if the character is the last one in the text input (without getting out of the loop)?

No.

`stdin` is best thought of as a *stream* of data.   Code cannot know beforehand if end-of-file or enter (`'\n'`) will arrive

---

> How to detect last character in a C string when within a getchar() loop

Instead  detect when end-of-file occurs and operate on the previous character after the loop.

```
printf("Enter in your text\n");

int previous = EOF;
int c;
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF) {
  previous = c;  
}

do_something(previous);
```

---

If one needs the character before <kbd>enter</kbd>, `while ((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {` would suffice.

Comment: This even though accepted, does not answer the question of how to detect the last character before user presses **enter**

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  The "last one in the text input" can be considered _end-of-file_ and not before _enter_ as you suggest.  Given OP's `(c=getchar()) != EOF`, seeking end-of-file is a stronger candidate than looking for `'\n'`.  [To each his own](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20each%20his%20own).

Comment: OP's question does include comment `if (last_char) // the last character before the user presses enter.`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala True - fair enough.

Comment: In fact OP's post includes 3 distinct and dissimilar questions :F

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If one needs the character before _enter_, `while ((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {` would suffice.

Comment: I cant remove my downvote unless you edit your question. Otoh the 3rd sentence of OPs asks "without breaking the loop" or something...

Answer (score 3):

Something list this?

```
printf("Enter in your text\n");
int c,last_char;
do
{
    c = getchar();
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        // it's the last char... do something with last_char
        printf("\nThe last char was: %c\n", last_char);
    }

    last_char = c;

} while (c != EOF);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about-

```
int c = 0;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);

        // assuming that ';' is the character. you can change
        // this to any acceptable character here
        if(c == ';')
        {
            printf("\nYou entered ';' character\n");
            // do something here
        }
    }
```